# Wkhtmltopdf: text wrapping issue

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have a text without spaces in html and want to convert it to pdf using wkhtmltopdf, but I met some wrapping issue. Text is wrapped on other point in pdf, as on image:

http://irok84.kei.pl/share/wrap.png

Anyone knows a reason or solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, adding the css rule

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the text container fixes the problem.

Comment: What if I want to break it to new line, and still it works as links considering multiple lines after break?

Comment: @mosabbirtuhin Hi, this answer is old and wkh... has probably changed a lot. The soft was(is?) so buggy/heavy that in 7 years its pretty likely they had to change a lot of stuff ;-)